# Audio Cable for 220v Led Lamps

Tags: led, audio

Is there a way I can stress test a 'common' electric audio cable?
I have a very cheap one that unfortunately holds no info on max Wattage.

I want to re-do the electric cables of my parent's old lamp as the current one is all broken. The idea is to use 12x3W LED E14 220v bulbs. That'd be a total of 36W, which in theory should be enough for an audio cable. But would it support such a high Voltage?

Bit of a noob here, so forgive me for anything weird I might have said :)
Cheers

Comment: No, because audio cable has no additional mantle which is required for mains cabling in/on metal frames. You may use single wires and put an additional silicone sheath over each one but honestly, simply buy a cable intended for that purpose.

Comment: You can go to your local hardware store and get proper mains rated electrical cable capable of the amps you need.

Comment: The wattage isn't the problem, the voltage is. Audio cables simply don't have insulation designed to withstand the same high voltages that mains cable must.

Comment: Yeah, as others have said, DON'T DO IT - buy some cable with a mains rating, stay safe :)

Answer (score -1):

If your audio cables are like these AWG 20, they are rated for 300Vac and 3kV spark rated and 2kVac HiPOT tested.

http://www.tensility.com/pdffiles/30-00353.pdf

If not, who knows?  If the insulation is >=0.5mm, it will be OK. Normally 5kV/mm

But this is how it is tested per spec above.